# Grails not running

Tags: grails

I am trying to run grails in my laptop, I have installed jdk 1.8.0 and jre8, I have set JAVA_HOME and GRAILS_HOME correctly. When I type %JAVA_HOME% or %GRAILS_HOME% in command prompt, it displays correct paths. But when I try to run any grails command, I get the following error:

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
| Error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:1208)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings$configureDependencyManager.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.postLoadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1121)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1003)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:978)
```

My laptop has windows 8.
Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this before you create any project ?

Comment: yes, right after setting the environment variables.

Comment: where exactly your java home is pointing? make sure JAVA_HOME points to a jdk, not just a jvm

Comment: It is pointed to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"

Comment: Do you have `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in your `PATH`?

Answer (score 25):

I was using java8, I tried using java7 and it worked fine! Apparently grails does not work with java8

Comment: also just a side note.  JAVA_HOME needs to be set correctly as well.  Gentoo allows me to set user vm, but does not change JAVA_HOME correctly as times.  Double check your JAVA_HOME

Comment: Using Grails 2.2.3 and JDK 8 had the same issue. Runs fine with JDK7

Answer (score 3):

grails 2.4 works with jdk - 8. grails 2.1.1 works with jdk - 7.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Grails 2.5.0 to run on jdk8u40+.

Also, if you are using the IDE GGTS, make sure it is v3.6.4, and that you install Groovy 2.4 from the extensions page to get the show on the road.

Answer (score 0):

for my case, I re-synced the JDK home link. I use quite a few java versions these days.

after install the intrusive jdk1.8.0_51. THE `/Library/Java/Home` get overridden (maybe in most cases intended).  if you just want to play with jdk1.8 and works mainly under other versions, you should link this place back

Answer (score -1):

Now Grails 3+ version support java8 and there are lots of feature with new build system and also integrated spring boot. So you can update your project with grails 3+ version. But you need to Change your application architecture cause of spring boot and gradle build system.